click event element in popUp mapbox
Hi guys I have a problem, I'm trying to call method that is inside a popUp of Mapbox library, this is my code, all code is in ngOnInit lifecycle for the moment I triend to put a method in a div of pup, but doesn't work , I was found if this is a repeat question but I don't find nothinf :C :<

  @ViewChild('map') map!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChildren('markerElement') markerElements!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.placesService.getUserLocation().then(() => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.map.nativeElement,
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
        center: this.placesService.userLocation,
        zoom: 14,
      });

      const arrayMarkers = [
        {
          coordinates: [-76.9618471, -12.1839679],
          name: 'SJM Calle 4'
        }, {
          coordinates: [-76.9570835, -12.1811625],
          name: 'SJM Calle7'
        }
      ];

      arrayMarkers.forEach((item,index) => {
        const popupContent = `
          <h6>Aquí estoy</h6>
          <div id="markerElement-${index}">
            <span>${item.name}</span>
          </div>
        `;

        const popup = new Popup()
          .setHTML(popupContent);

        new Marker({ color: 'red' }).setLngLat(item.coordinates)
          .setPopup(popup)
          .addTo(map);

        // Obtener una referencia al elemento div después de que se ha creado
        // const markerElement = this.markerElement.nativeElement;

        // // Agregar un detector de eventos al elemento div
        // markerElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //   this.redirect(item);
        // });
        console.log(this.markerElements);

        this.markerElements.forEach((markerElement, index) => {
          console.log('111');

          markerElement.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.handleMarkerClick(index);
          });
        });
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      alert('no hay ubicacion');
    });
  }


